# NSDictionaryResultType vs NSManagedObjectResultType

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working on fetching the distinct data and I set resulttype to NSDictionaryResultType and it will return 10 distincts data which is good, but I want that data to be in NSManagedObjectResultType.

```
  [fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:pageid, pagename,  nil]];
  [fetch setReturnsDistinctResults : YES];
  [fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

I also used NSManagedObjectResultType, but it does not return the distinct data and it returns 30 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `returnsDistinctResults` only for NSDictionaryResultType 
here is the API Description

> Returns/sets if the fetch request returns only distinct values for the
>   fields specified by propertiesToFetch. This value is only used for
>   NSDictionaryResultType. Defaults to NO.

Comment: so how can i get the distinct data by using propertiesToFetch in NSManagedObjectResultType?

Comment: Try searching on how to convert dictionary to managed object.